# addform select2 not working when add new input

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-select2

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#btn-tambah-form").click(function(){ 
                var jumlah = parseInt($("#jumlah-form").val()); 
                var nextform = jumlah + 1;
                // Kita akan menambahkan form dengan menggunakan append
                // pada sebuah tag div yg kita beri id insert-form
                $("#insert-form").append(
                    "<div class='row mb-10 p-10'>" +
                    "   <div class='input-group  col-md-3'>" +
                    "       <select class='form-control select2' name='akun_biaya[]' id='akun_biaya"+nextform+"' style='width: 100%;' required>" +
                    "       <option></option>" +
                    "       <?php $query2 = mysqli_query($conn,'select a.*, b.* from akun a left join akun_kategori b on a.akun_jenis = b.kategori_nomor'); ?>" +
                    "           <?php while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){ ?>" +
                    "           <?php echo '<option value=\''.$data2['akun_nomor'].'\'>'.$data2['akun_nomor'].' | '.$data2['akun_nama'].' ('.$data2['kategori_nama'].')</option>';  } ?>" +
                    "       </select>" +
                    "   </div>" +
                    "   <div class='input-group  col-md-3'>" +
                    "       <input class='form-control' type='text' name='uraian[]' id='uraian"+nextform+"'>" +
                    "   </div>" +
                    "   <div class='input-group col-md-2'>" +
                    "       <select class='form-control' name='pajak[]' id='pajak"+nextform+"' style='width: 100%;' onchange='sum();'>" +
                    "           <?php echo Pajak();?>" +
                    "       </select>" +
                    "   </div>" +
                    "   <div class='input-group col-md-4'>" +
                    "       <span class='input-group-addon'>Rp.</span><input class='form-control' type='number' name='subtotal[]' id='subtotal"+nextform+"' value='0' onkeyup='sum();'>" +
                    "   </div>" +
                    "</div>");
    
                    
                $("#jumlah-form").val(nextform); // Ubah value textbox jumlah-form dengan variabel nextform
            });
            
            // Buat fungsi untuk mereset form ke semula
            $("#btn-reset-form").click(function(){
                $("#insert-form").html(""); // Kita kosongkan isi dari div insert-form
                $("#jumlah-form").val("1"); // Ubah kembali value jumlah form menjadi 1
            });
            
        });
```

I'm creating some application from my office but I have a problem in addform for select2. It's not working when I add a new input form. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand very well, do you need to add `select2` to the new created elements?

Comment: yes sir because combobox have many item on it.

Comment: You have imported select2 lib, right? Check my answer to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a new element, you need to initialize select2 to the created content, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#btn-tambah-form").click(function(){ 
                var jumlah = parseInt($("#jumlah-form").val()); 
                var nextform = jumlah + 1;
                // Kita akan menambahkan form dengan menggunakan append
                // pada sebuah tag div yg kita beri id insert-form
                $("#insert-form").append(
                    "<div class='row mb-10 p-10'>" +
                    "   <div class='input-group  col-md-3'>" +
                    "       <select class='form-control select2' name='akun_biaya[]' id='akun_biaya"+nextform+"' style='width: 100%;' required>" +
                    "       <option></option>" +
                    "       <?php $query2 = mysqli_query($conn,'select a.*, b.* from akun a left join akun_kategori b on a.akun_jenis = b.kategori_nomor'); ?>" +
                    "           <?php while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){ ?>" +
                    "           <?php echo '<option value=\''.$data2['akun_nomor'].'\'>'.$data2['akun_nomor'].' | '.$data2['akun_nama'].' ('.$data2['kategori_nama'].')</option>';  } ?>" +
                    "       </select>" +
                    "   </div>" +
                    "   <div class='input-group  col-md-3'>" +
                    "       <input class='form-control' type='text' name='uraian[]' id='uraian"+nextform+"'>" +
                    "   </div>" +
                    "   <div class='input-group col-md-2'>" +
                    "       <select class='form-control' name='pajak[]' id='pajak"+nextform+"' style='width: 100%;' onchange='sum();'>" +
                    "           <?php echo Pajak();?>" +
                    "       </select>" +
                    "   </div>" +
                    "   <div class='input-group col-md-4'>" +
                    "       <span class='input-group-addon'>Rp.</span><input class='form-control' type='number' name='subtotal[]' id='subtotal"+nextform+"' value='0' onkeyup='sum();'>" +
                    "   </div>" +
                    "</div>");
    
                    
                $("#jumlah-form").val(nextform); // Ubah value textbox jumlah-form dengan variabel nextform

                $(".select2").select2(); // <-- initializing select2
            });
            
            // Buat fungsi untuk mereset form ke semula
            $("#btn-reset-form").click(function(){
                $("#insert-form").html(""); // Kita kosongkan isi dari div insert-form
                $("#jumlah-form").val("1"); // Ubah kembali value jumlah form menjadi 1
            });
            
        });
```